# Android: Keep a thread running even if the device is locked

Tags: android, alarm

I'm making an alarm app for android. Once the user scheduled an alarm, a thread will count until the alarm is reached and then there will be an alarm sound.

However, the counting thread *stops* when the device is locked (I mean when the screen turns off after half a minute) and continue from where it left if it is unlocked again - even if that is hours later.

That makes for a pretty weird alarm app. I've looked into AlarmManager, but it seems like it's not appropriate in my case, since I only want the alarm to happen *if* my app is still running. Quitting the app should stop it. Here's what AlarmManager's documentation says though:

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended
>   for cases where you want to have your
>   application code run at a specific
>   time, even if your application is not
>   currently running. For normal timing
>   operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it
>   is easier and much more efficient to
>   use Handler.

The "Handler" class it mentions seems to be intended for something entirely different from what I'm trying to achieve.

So I'm asking you: How can I keep my thread alive and counting even if the device is locked? Or is there another way?

Comment: Can you set some state on App shutdown, and read it on alarm event later?

Comment: You say that you only want the alarm to happen if your app is still "running." What does "running" mean to your app? Android's idea might be different than what you want your app to convey to the user here.

Answer (score 2):

You need not not doing this. Don't keep  a thread around for an alarm. Use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Also there's no concept of your app "running" or not. Do you mean only when it's visible? Just clear your alarm in onPause().

Answer (score 0):

Why using not using Notifications? You can set sound, vibrating, lights and a showing an icon in the status bar. If you want to cancel the Notification use the NotificationManager.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateANotification

Geert

Comment: I do use NotificationManager, but can I also schedule notifications to a later time?

Comment: You can tell them when to happen or do you mean 10 times in 10 seconds??